# What is the difference between sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException and org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException

Tags: java, notimplementedexception

I have discovered there are 2 NotImplementedException:

- sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException
- org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException

Since there is not an available documentation for the first one, I'm not able to understand the difference between them.
What is this difference? Is one of them better than the other one?

Comment: The first one is described as ["Temporary class used to indicate missing functionality"](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/NotImplementedException.java) and as it's part of `sun` and has no clear usage instructions, it's probably not intended for whatever use you were thinking about.

Comment: "Is one of them better than the other one?" I heard the `sun.reflect` one has more exceptional goodness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have discovered there are 2 `NotImplementedException`

I found more examples than that.  It depends on how hard you look ... and where.

---

> Since there is not an available documentation for the first one ...

That is because `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException` is an *internal* class.  The source code says:

> *"Temporary class used to indicate missing functionality"*

---

> What is this difference?

They both mean the same thing, more or less.  Some piece of functionality has not been implemented.

---

> Is one of them better than the other one?

I assume that you are really asking whether you can and should reuse either of these exceptions in your code.

1. Since the `sun.reflect...` exception is an internal class (see @GhostCat's answer), it is *inadvisable* to use it in your code.  There is a chance that the class will "go away" in a future release of Java<sup>1</sup>.  That will present problems for your codebase.
2. It is reasonable to reuse the `org.apache.commons...` exception.  Indeed, my reading of the javadoc, it is *designed* to be *generally* reusable.  However:

   - It is not standard.
   - In fact, there are at least two versions of this class, in `org.apache.commons.lang` and `org.apache.commons.lang3`.  (See bullet #1!)
   - You would be (potentially) be adding a new dependency on Apache Commons.  That could increase your maintenance costs; e.g. if someone were to find security issues in Apache Commons that required patching.  Also, if your company has anti-opensource management or lawyers ... the effort in getting them to grant an exception to a corporate "no opensource" policy might be too much.
3. The other alternatives are to declare your own custom exception, or simply use the existing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` ... which **is** standard, **doesn't** add a new dependency,  and **won't** be removed in a future Java release.

---

<sup>1.  I'm not sure of this, but I think that access to `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects` is blocked in Java 9.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty simple: *anything* that lives in a package starting *sun...* is (almost always) safe to ignore (there are some rare exceptions, like *sun.misc.Unsafe*)

In other words: these packages that still come with the JDK/JRE are *not* meant for public usage. Even when they provide something *useful* - you better look out for "really public" alternatives. The main purpose of such classes is to help implementing "internals" of the JVM. They are completely out of your control, and there are almost no "guarantees" whatsoever what happens to them over time.

In that sense the answer is: that *sun* exception is one that you simply should not use; whereas the apache commons one *might* be a good candidate. The whole point of the commons classes is to be used "publicly".

Answer (score 4):

I can answer with this. What is the difference between
`com.your.package.NotImplementedException` and `org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException`?

The `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException` is `JDK` internal API, not for usage in user code.