# The type sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException is not accessible

Tags: java

**I have tried to import the package as below:**

```
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;
```

**Then I:**

```
public static int specialSummation(int number) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**But it comes out with these errors:**

```
The type sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException is not accessible
NotImplementedException cannot be resolved to a type
```

Does anyone have clues with this errors? Thanks very much!

Comment: It's for internal use only, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418641/what-is-the-difference-between-sun-reflect-generics-reflectiveobjects-notimpleme